# Cannot import class file from Java project into another class file in the same project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, package

I have a Java Maven project in Eclipse (2021-09 (4.21.0)) and am trying to import a class called `BaseTest.java` into another class (`ElementFetch.java`) within the same project, but in a separate package. If you look at the screenshot below, you will see my `import src.test.java.youtubeframework.BaseTest;` statement and will note the error indicator on line 5. Regardless of the paths I specify:

```
import youtubeframework.src.test.java.youtubeframework.BaseTest;
import src.test.java.youtubeframework.BaseTest; 
import test.java.youtubeframework.BaseTest;
import java.youtubeframework.BaseTest;
import youtubeframework.BaseTest;
import BaseTest;
```

the import will not work. There is always an error which prevents the import from working.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image: My Eclipse Project setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are using the source path for the class as if it was the package name. The correct package name should be `youtubeframework`.  So you should (in theory) use `import youtubeframework.BaseTest`.

But the second problem is that your "main" Java code cannot depend on your "test" Java code.  That is why `import youtubeframework.BaseTest` doesn't work.

In the Maven view of the world, the "test" tree is for code that is only used for testing the stuff in the "main" tree:

- "test" classes can depends on "main" classes.
- "main" classes cannot depend on "test" classes.

If you have a "test" class that is used by something in the "main" tree, then it is actually part of your application / library / whatever, and it should be in the "main" tree.

Comment: BINGO! That solved the problem! I added a new package called "base" to src/main/java and now the import works with a simple: import base.BaseTest Thank you!!!